# Selecting a Range depended on two Key Words

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project to create a VBA to automatically delete blank lines. I have created the following with some help:

```
    Dim rngFirst As Range
    Dim rngLast As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("Input")
        'Find the start and stop
        Set rngFirst = .Cells.Find(what:="[Performance Income]", lookat:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
        Set rngLast = .Cells.Find(what:="[Miscellaneous Income]", _
            lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)

        .Range(rngFirst, rngLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I am having a 1004 Run Time error. I have searched for the reason why I think it has something to do with my range selection. However I don't know specifically, I was hoping to get help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should always check first the items are found before processing to avoid errors. Step through your code to see if either variable is Nothing which means the search term was not found.

Comment: Are the [ and ] visibly included in the cell‘s values?

Comment: @Asger The square brackets are not part of the cell's value. I took them off in code however the same errors occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me.

You have to make sure the first range is a cell before the last one and they are located in the same column. Otherwise it throws an error.

To define the new range, use the Address property of the start and finish ranges.

```
Sub DeleteBlankCells()

    Dim rngFirst As Range
    Dim rngLast As Range

    Dim rngUnion As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("Input")
        'Find the start and stop
        Set rngFirst = .Cells.Find(what:="Performance Income", lookat:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
        Set rngLast = .Cells.Find(what:="Miscellaneous Income", _
            lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)

        Set rngUnion = Range(rngFirst.Address, rngLast.Address)

        rngUnion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I realized I made a foolish mistake. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! If my solution helped you, please consider marking the answer

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't convince me. The two found ranges should be checked against `Nothing` and that's it. The original code will delete any row in the whole range containing a blank cell. The ranges neither have to be in the same column, nor does the first be located before the last, nor do you need a `Union` nor do you have to use their address.