# Selecting Range between two words then based on a different column deleting them

Tags: excel, vba

I made an original post ([Selecting a Range depended on two Key Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542141/selecting-a-range-depended-on-two-key-words/54542937#54542937)). My code was correct however it doesn't do what I needed it to do. I need help/ guidance to manipulate the code so that between Revenue and total revenue we look at column J if it is empty the entire row is deleted. I tried my best but as I am currently learning VBA I am struggling to find even how to approach it.

[image: Excel File]

Code thus far:

```
Dim rngFirst As Range
Dim rngLast As Range

Dim rngUnion As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Input")
    'Find the start and stop
    Set rngFirst = .Cells.Find(what:="Performance Income", lookat:=xlWhole, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
    Set rngLast = .Cells.Find(what:="Miscellaneous Income", _
        lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)

    Set rngUnion = Range(rngFirst.Address, rngLast.Address)

    rngUnion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I appreciate all the help thus far and any help given. Thank you.

Comment: You appear to be posting the same question again. What's different here? What exactly is the problem? Did you read my comment on your previous question?

Comment: "My code was correct however it doesn't do what I needed it to do". [...huh?](https://i.imgur.com/jusLe9J.gif)  How's the code correct if it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: @BruceWayne I should have explained it better. What I meant to say was the code runs without issue however I need help getting it to delete based on another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use `Match` to find the rows where "Revenue" and "Total Revenue" are. Then check between these rows if there are blanks in column J `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` and delete the `EntireRow`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteEmpty()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet 'define worksheet
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next 'Next line throws error if  "Revenue" or "Total Revenue" is not found
    FirstRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Revenue", wsInput.Range("A:A"), False) + 1
    LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total Revenue", wsInput.Range("A:A"), False) - 1
    On Error GoTo 0 'Always re-activate error handling!

    'Check if both "Revenue" and "Total Revenue" were found
    If FirstRow = 0 Or LastRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Revenue or Total Revenue not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Find empty cells in column J between FirstRow (Revenue) and LastRow (Total Revenue)
    Dim EmptyCellsInJ As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set EmptyCellsInJ = wsInput.Range(wsInput.Cells(FirstRow, "J"), wsInput.Cells(LastRow, "J")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If there are empty cells delete their rows
    If Not EmptyCellsInJ Is Nothing Then
        EmptyCellsInJ.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing to delete"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really cool. Thank you for the help hopefully I get as good as you haha.